# Angularjs Dom leaking in loading templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, memory-leaks, timeline

I have an angular-restful application where I have a list like this:[image]

Whenever I click on one of these items I make an ajax call to retrieve data but I also call this directive to load different templates

```
    .directive('contentItem', function ($compile) { 

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            element.html( scope.templates[scope.rec.htmlType]);     

            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
                element.remove();                   
            }); 
    }

    return {            
        link: linker,
        scope: {
            rec:'=',
            templates: '=',             
        }
    };
})
```

and here is my html

```
<tr ng-repeat="rec in ctrl.correctionRows">
 <td content-item rec="rec" templates="templates" ></td>
</tr>
```

But then here is how my timeline looks like in Chrome, after clicking and opening only ten of those items, my browser crashes and apparently runs out of memory
[image]
I have even tried to force $on("$destroy" to remove elements, but anyway doesn't work for me. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.
I even tried to hard code the templates and html type so that I removed the scope

```
            scope: {
            rec:'=',
            templates: '=',             
        }
```

it didn't make it any better!

Now I have removed the directive for testing purposes, because I thought that's the main source of memory leakage, but no! Right now I only have an accordion with 3 inner ng-repeat and small controller inside them! But still this is how I get the output
[image]

Comment: what is inside your template? `scope.templates[scope.rec.htmlType]`, recursive? also element.remove() on scope $destroy is no meaning, it should automatically removed.

Comment: no templates is just a json file containing stuff like different templates: {
  "input": "<input ng-model='rec.correctionTo' class='form-control' ng-change='$parent.rowHasChanged(rec)' placeholder='{{rec.correctionTo}}' id='input{{ $index }}' />"}

Comment: @YOU when for example I have a htmlType of input I load input template, if I have checkbox, I load check template and so on.

Comment: I see, may be checkout watchers increasing or not too - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk?hl=en - if so $scope is leaking. are you also doing $scope.$new somewhere too?

Comment: may be remove `scope: {
            rec:'=',
            templates: '=',             
        }` - looks like you don't really need new scope. I guess it will copy your objects to child scope.

Comment: @YOU No I don't have $scope.$new any where. I have just added the html markup that I have. If I remove these two, then I won't have templates and more importantly the current record. That's the way I am passing my dynamic data to the directive. But I can try to hard code it to see if it is the scope that causes the leak.

Comment: You might be better off using `template: '<div ng-include="rec.htmlType"></div>'` to swap templates instead of using `.html()` and `$compile`.  Direct DOM manipulations in Angular always seem to lead to disaster.

Comment: @DanielBeck but according to these two documents i was told that ng-include is slow compared to using templates! http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

Comment: @Shilan I think you've misread that document; you have it backwards: the performance hit comes from manually re-`$compile`ing your templates each time you load the directive rather than depending on angular's built-in template management to keep them compiled and ready to go as needed.

Comment: @Shilan, ng-include do slow, but if you use $compile it yourself, not much better. - http://plnkr.co/edit/be2h0vgxvgmkOjfafHoD?p=preview

Comment: (You could, of course, mitigate some of that performance hit by precompiling and caching each of your templates rather than recompiling in each directive link -- at which point you would have successfully reinvented angular's built-in template stash, except with bonus memory leaks.)

Comment: @DanielBeck  Thanks for your advises, To test it, I totally removed the directive! now I only have 3 inner ng repeat with different small controllers inside them. The memory leakage didn't get any better.

Comment: @YOU thanks for your great plunker, I am looking into that. but as I tested the app, it is not only the directive, it seems that these 3 inner ngRepeats are problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after all I upgraded angularjs to 1.4 and also changed to templateCache and templateUrl and yes! it doesn't leak anymore, and doesn't crash the browser.
Here is my new directive

```
.directive('hymn', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
          return attrs.templateUrl;
      }
    }
})
```

and since templateUrl has a bug calling every time from the GUI
I just added a funny markup in html page like this

```
<td ng-switch="rec.htmlType">           
       <hymn ng-switch-when="input" template-url="app/correction/templates/htmltype/input.html"  ></hymn> 
       <hymn ng-switch-when="label" template-url="app/correction/templates/htmltype/label.html"  ></hymn> 
       <hymn ng-switch-when="check" template-url="app/correction/templates/htmltype/check.html"  ></hymn> 
       <hymn ng-switch-when="datepicker" template-url="app/correction/templates/htmltype/datepicker.html"  ></hymn>           
       <hymn ng-switch-when="typeahead-country" template-url="app/correction/templates/htmltype/typeahead-country.html"  ></hymn> 
       <hymn ng-switch-default template-url="app/correction/templates/htmltype/input.html"  ></hymn> 
    </td>
```

May not seem beautiful, but actually doesn't leak and works fine!